# Create composite index from right skewed data with extreme outliers

Tags: mathematical-statistics, skewness, social-science, economics

Do you have any advice for creating an index from right skewed-data with several extreme outliers.

I am new to creating indexes for analysis and could use some advice.  So far I've done things like dividing values by the maximum value to create an index, but in this case I am dealing with large outliers.

What are my options.  I need something simple to explain in a business setting.

Thoughts on the below options: 
1) option one creating ranked values from quartiles

```
Using Simple Code for an Example in R
library(dplyr)

df$quartile_span <- ntile(df$right_skewed_variable, 4))  # get quartile values

#create the index 
df$index <- df$quartile_span / max(df$quartile_span) # the max would be four
```

2) option two - create index from the normally distributed variable

```
logs_val <- log(df$right_skewed_variable)

# create the index using natural log values 
df$index <- logs_val / max(logs_val)
```

Other advice is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by an index?

Comment: A composite index - that is typically between zero and one.  Something like this.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Development_Index